# How to do a second Webview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

inside my Webview App I want to call a second website after a quick pause.

Unfortunately it looks like the pause between the first and the second link dont work...

I dont know why can u give me a tip pls :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private WebView webView;
 private WebSettings Websetting;
 private WebView webView2;
 private WebSettings webSettings2;

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
     Websetting = webView.getSettings();
     Websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     Websetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     webView.loadUrl("https://google.de");
     webView.clearHistory();

     try {
         Thread.activeCount();
         Thread.sleep(15000); //1000 milliseconds is one second.
         webView2 = findViewById(R.id.webView);
         Websetting = webView2.getSettings();
         Websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         Websetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
         webView2.loadUrl("https://google.com");
         webView2.clearHistory();
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();

     }

 }
}

´´´
```

Comment: Whats happening? Theyare loading at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Postdelayed method :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private WebView webView;
 private WebSettings Websetting;
 private WebView webView2;
 private WebSettings webSettings2;

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
     Websetting = webView.getSettings();
     Websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     Websetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     webView.loadUrl("https://google.de");
     webView.clearHistory();

    
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView2 = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                Websetting = webView2.getSettings();
                Websetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                Websetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView2.loadUrl("https://google.com");
                webView2.clearHistory();
            }
        }, 15000);
     }
    

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following code within the run braces

```
webView2 = findViewById(R.id.webView2);
```